# Which should I choice device itself or server to save data?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm very new to developing iOS & Android apps with Flutter.
And, have a simple question If I should use device memory(client hereafter) or sever such as Firebase to save non-temporary data? And I also understand of course it depends on what I develop or how I design it, but I want it known in a general way.

For example, in chatting Apps such as Facebook Messenger, Snapchat, or WhatsApp, are those chat history, images, or other staff saved in their client, server-side, or both?

Or in the case to develop to do Apps, and If I expect not to users to share their to-do lists, those data should be memorized only by their client or on the server side?

I want to know the kind of criteria, If the developer expects that Apps would be used more than 1G data for the non-temporary data (such as chatting history), we should use server-side as memory, or like images always should be memorized on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I should use device memory(client hereafter) or sever such as firebase to save non-temporary data.

It really depends on what you need to store. So you can save the data into a local data structure or even a local database, only if you need that data when the application restarts. Please note that when using this solution, the data won't survive if the user clears the cache or if it uninstalls the app. When doing that, the data is wiped away.

Storing data in the Cloud, it's an even better idea. Why? Because no matter what happens with the app, the data will always be present there.

> For example, in chat apps such as Facebook Messenger, Snapchat, or WhatsApp, are those chat history, images, or other staff saved in their client, server-side, or both?

Both. Why? Because if the user goes offline, the app needs a cached copy of the data, so the user can continue to use the app while the device is offline.

> Or in case to develop to do Apps, and If I expect not to the user to share their to-do list, those data should be memorized only by their client or on the server side?

If you want to create an app in which the users should only use their lists, then there is no need to add the data to an online database. But keep in mind that if the user uninstalls the app, all the data goes away, which is some kind of bad user experience.

> I want to know the kind of criteria, if developers expect that apps would be using more than 1G data for the non-temporary data (such as chatting history), we should use server-side as memory, or like images always should be memorized in server side.

That's a limitation that you as a developer should set it. So according to how much data you want to serve, you can set 1 Gb, 2 Gb, or whatever is needed. Regarding photos, you should use a library that can help you cache the photos locally. This means that once you download an image, later, it always be displayed from the cache. If the user uninstalls the app, then the next time launches the app, a single download of the image will be performed, and later it will be served from the cache again.

When it comes to Firebase, bear in mind that both [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) and the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) have their own offline persistence mechanisms. So using one of these databases, or why not even both, you'll don't have to manage any local caches.

Comment: Thanks for comment  and sorry for the late reply.
Finally, I choose to use both FireStore for permanent data and Hive for local data. I understood what you mean about what I should save data for and the tools must be depends on the purpose.